# Why is `tf.reduce_mean` used when computing the accuracy of logistic regression?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, logistic-regression

The following function is meant to calculate accuracy of logistic regression, but what is the point of using `reduce_mean` function in this function?

The code is:

```
import tensorflow as tf    
def accuracy(y_pred, y_true):
        # Predicted class is the index of the highest score in prediction vector (i.e. argmax).
    
        correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_pred, 1), tf.cast(y_true, tf.int64))
    
        return tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, note that the metric or loss functions usually expect a batch of prediction/true labels as input. Now, each element of `correct_prediction` is `True` if the corresponding prediction is correct; otherwise, it's `False`. Then, `tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32)` would convert `True` values to 1 and `False` values to 0. So, computing the average (i.e. mean) of it would be equivalent to the accuracy of predictions (though, as a value in range [0,1], and not as a percentage).

To further clarify this, consider this:

```py
>>> correct_prediction
[True, False, False, True, True]    # 3 out of 5 predictions are correct

>>> tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32)
[1, 0, 0, 1, 1]

>>> tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
0.6    # it means 60% accuracy which is what we expected
```